# How to align(stylise) images properly in static block in Magento

Tags: magento-2.1, static-block

How can I add images side by side not one by one in static block?

**I created new block like**
[image: I created new block like this]

**And I got result as**
[image: My result]

**But I need like this**
[image: I got result]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about css

Comment: I thought it was the issue with Magento's wysiwyg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a case of adding images side by side, you just manually select the images you want to display in your `static block` and force them to stand next to eachother with `CSS`

if you have put a `div` around your images you can do something like:

```
#divname img{float:left;}
```

But you have to provide more code for me to know what CSS rule you should use

Comment: I figured out the solution based on your answer. I edited style.css "line 213" by adding float: left;